# Eclipse + PyDev: file reopens in debug mode

Tags: eclipse, debugging, pydev

I use Eclipse (4.2.1) to develop Python (3.2) programs using PyDev (2.8.2). I start my program in debug mode and when I encounter the first breakpoint, a new tab is opened with a copy of the script containing the breakpoint.

- Debugging then takes places in the new copy.
- When I stop debugging, the tab with the copy remains.
- Changes to the copy, must be saved to update the original tab.

How can I make Eclipse NOT open a separate copy of my program?

**Status: I still have this problem!**